# PyQt. Нарисовать объект QImage на диалоговом окне(QDialog)

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, qimage

Не могу отобразить объект QImage на диалоговом окне(QDialog)
[image: Здесь необходима вставить объект]
Нужен работающий код, который нарисует здесь синий квадрат

Comment: Опубликуйте пожалуйста пример, демонстрирующий проблему.

Comment: А что нам за это будет?